# How to update the fill and sorting the values of lollipop chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to change the fill of the circles in my lollipop chart, as well as the order (sorting from largest to lowest) depending on the button the user clicks. I've successfully changed my y axis depending on the value but I'm having problems trying to change the other parameters.

Here's the csv I'm using:

```
media_outlet,positive,negative,balanced,informational,total
La Opinión,149,296,142,101,688
Wall Street Journal,137,118,125,79,459
Univision,226,484,225,159,1094
San Diego Union Tribune,60,24,18,17,119
Fox News,73,102,58,60,293
Washington Post,52,97,56,50,255
CNN,127,160,102,88,477
USA Today,32,23,14,22,91
The Daily Beast,9,50,13,10,82
Bloomberg,251,183,158,119,711
Fusion,48,86,54,49,237
NPR,20,30,12,14,76
Dallas Morning News,40,34,24,31,129
TIME,26,30,17,17,90
Forbes,97,56,72,37,262
Christian Science Monitor,19,15,21,7,62
NBC News,23,34,19,22,98
Huffington Post,232,344,219,85,880
New York TImes,90,129,74,62,355
Houston Chronicle,40,32,31,24,127
Los Angeles Times,66,75,45,45,231
San Antonio Express News,28,22,14,16,80
Arizona Daily Star,32,15,6,8,61
Vice News,17,169,44,12,242
```

My Javascript code starting the visualization sorting the chart with the total (I haven't figured out how or where to apply the sorting in the code when the button gets clicked):

```
const svg = d3
  .select('#outlets-viz')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// Initialize the X axis
const x = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(1);

const xAxis = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

// Initialize the Y axis
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

const yAxis = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'myYaxis');


// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(selectedVar) {
  // Parse the Data

  d3.csv('../data/media_tendency.csv').then(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.positive = +d.positive;
      d.negative = +d.negative;
      d.balanced = +d.balanced;
      d.informational = +d.informational;
      d.total = +d.total;
    });

    console.log(data);

    data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.total < b.total) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });

    // X axis
    x.domain(
      data.map(function(d) {
        return d.media_outlet;
      })
    );

    xAxis
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)rotate(-40)')
      .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    // Add Y axis
    y.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return +d[selectedVar];
      }),
    ]);

    yAxis
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // variable u: map data to existing circle
    const j = svg.selectAll('.myLine').data(data);
    // update lines
    j.enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('class', 'myLine')
      .merge(j)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('x1', function(d) {
        //console.log(x(d.media_outlet));
        return x(d.media_outlet);
      })
      .attr('x2', function(d) {
        return x(d.media_outlet);
      })
      .attr('y1', y(0))
      .attr('y2', function(d) {
        return y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr('stroke', 'grey');

    // variable u: map data to existing circle
    const u = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);
    // update bars
    u.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .merge(u)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return x(d.media_outlet);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        if (d[selectedVar] === 'total') {
          return '#bfc0c1';
        } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'positive') {
          return '#5cdacc';
        } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'negative') {
          return '#ff1d34';
        } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'balanced') {
          return '#ffc750';
        } else {
          return '#ff8c50';
        }
      });
  });
}

update('total');
```

An my html:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="positive p-2" onclick="update('positive')">
            Positive
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="negative p-2" onclick="update('negative')">
            Negative
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="balanced p-2" onclick="update('balanced')">
            Balanced
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="informational p-2" onclick="update('informational')">
            Informational
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="p-2" id="total-button" onclick="update('total')">
            Total
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm new to d3 and I've started coding a few months ago, any guidance on how to improve or change the code will help me so much! Thank you for your invaluable help :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding the color**:

Your `if` condition...

```
.attr('fill', function(d) {
    if (d[selectedVar] === 'total') {
      return '#bfc0c1';
    } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'positive') {
      return '#5cdacc';
    } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'negative') {
      return '#ff1d34';
    } else if (d[selectedVar] === 'balanced') {
      return '#ffc750';
    } else {
      return '#ff8c50';
    }
});
```

... is incorrect, since `total`, `positive`, `negative` etc... are **property** names, not values. It should be just `if(selectedVar === "total")` etc.

On top of that, you don't need that bunch of `if`s. Just use an scale:

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["positive", "negative", "balanced", "informational", "total"])
    .range(['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50', '#bfc0c1']);
```

And then it's as simple as:

```
.attr('fill', colorScale(selectedVar));
```

**Regarding the sorting issue**:

Use the property itself for sorting:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[selectedVar] - a[selectedVar];
});
```

Also, `sort` sorts in place, you don't need to reassign `data`.

Here is your updated code:

```js
const csv = `media_outlet,positive,negative,balanced,informational,total
La Opinión,149,296,142,101,688
Wall Street Journal,137,118,125,79,459
Univision,226,484,225,159,1094
San Diego Union Tribune,60,24,18,17,119
Fox News,73,102,58,60,293
Washington Post,52,97,56,50,255
CNN,127,160,102,88,477
USA Today,32,23,14,22,91
The Daily Beast,9,50,13,10,82
Bloomberg,251,183,158,119,711
Fusion,48,86,54,49,237
NPR,20,30,12,14,76
Dallas Morning News,40,34,24,31,129
TIME,26,30,17,17,90
Forbes,97,56,72,37,262
Christian Science Monitor,19,15,21,7,62
NBC News,23,34,19,22,98
Huffington Post,232,344,219,85,880
New York TImes,90,129,74,62,355
Houston Chronicle,40,32,31,24,127
Los Angeles Times,66,75,45,45,231
San Antonio Express News,28,22,14,16,80
Arizona Daily Star,32,15,6,8,61
Vice News,17,169,44,12,242`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.positive = +d.positive;
  d.negative = +d.negative;
  d.balanced = +d.balanced;
  d.informational = +d.informational;
  d.total = +d.total;
  return d;
});

const width = 500,
  height = 300;
const margin = {
  left: 30,
  right: 10,
  top: 10,
  bottom: 70
};

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// Initialize the X axis
const x = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(1);

const xAxis = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

// Initialize the Y axis
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

const yAxis = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'myYaxis');

const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["positive", "negative", "balanced", "informational", "total"])
  .range(['#5cdacc', '#ff1d34', '#ffc750', '#ff8c50', '#bfc0c1']);

// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(selectedVar) {
  // Parse the Data

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[selectedVar] - a[selectedVar];
  });

  // X axis
  x.domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.media_outlet;
    })
  );

  xAxis
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)rotate(-40)')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end');

  // Add Y axis
  y.domain([
    0,
    d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return +d[selectedVar];
    }),
  ]);

  yAxis
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // variable u: map data to existing circle
  const j = svg.selectAll('.myLine').data(data);
  // update lines
  j.enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('class', 'myLine')
    .merge(j)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      //console.log(x(d.media_outlet));
      return x(d.media_outlet);
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return x(d.media_outlet);
    })
    .attr('y1', y(0))
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return y(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'grey');

  // variable u: map data to existing circle
  const u = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);
  // update bars
  u.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return x(d.media_outlet);
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return y(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', colorScale(selectedVar));
}

update('total');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="positive p-2" onclick="update('positive')">
            Positive
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="negative p-2" onclick="update('negative')">
            Negative
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="balanced p-2" onclick="update('balanced')">
            Balanced
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="informational p-2" onclick="update('informational')">
            Informational
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="p-2" id="total-button" onclick="update('total')">
            Total
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```